# Scroll content is not fully visible to the user when user zooms to 175%

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have hidden the `<body>` scroll and given height with scroll for div, but the scroll content is not fully visible to the user when user zooms to 175%

```css
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}

div {
    height: 50rem;
    overflow-y: auto
}
```

How do I make the scroll content visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use vh height like `height:50vh`